# Is there a way to list the values of an object saved on Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

How to list the values present in the object saved in a hashmap

I'm trying to see if i can get a way to list the values i saved on a object, I'm storing in hashmap, but i don't know if it's possible to retrieve these values

```
HashMap<String, User> hashUser = new HashMap<String, User>();
hashUser.put(cont, new User(user, password));

hashUser.keySet().stream().forEach((x) -> {
            System.out.println(hashUser.??);
        });
```

basically my problem is the same as this guy [Displaying object values which are stored in a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41123600/displaying-object-values-which-are-stored-in-a-hashmap) well, it's kind of solved then

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--

Comment: Can you clarify "I'm trying to see if i can get a way to list the values i saved on a object"? What do you mean "values of an object"? Do you mean `user` and `password` values passed to `new User(user, password)`?

Comment: for example if i saved a user A with the password B, and i stored it inside an object and this object was saved inside a hashmap, i want to retrieve these values back, so basically i want to access the object saved in the hashmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Lutz Horn wrote in the comments you can use the `values()` method to retrieve the values of the hashmap.

```java
hashUser.values().forEach(user -> System.out.println("Username: " + user.getUsername() + " Password: "  + user.getPassword()));
```

Answer (score 0):

hashUser.values() returns a Collection of hashUser values.

Iterator userIterator = hashUser.values().iterator();

with Java 8 userIterator.forEachRemaining(System.out::println);